# Is it possible to change the font of a document in Apple Pages?

Tags: pages, font

I have an existing documents, many paragraphs being formatted with the style "Default", which is set to the font "Yuppy SC". Is it possible to change this font?

Of course I can set a font when writing new text (using Format/Font). I can also place the cursor somewhere in a paragraph formatted with "Default", then click Inspector/Format, and change the font in the format pane which has opened on the right of the document; but this changes only the font for the paragraph I'm in.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can change fonts. Go to 'Select All' under the Edit menu in the top menu bar. After selecting all, change the tab on the right sidebar to text and then set your new font and font size. This should change all the text in the document to your selected font.

Comment: This changes *all* the text in my document to a new font. This is obviously something I can do, but it is not what I want. As I said, I want the paragraphs, which have assigned the settuing named "Default" to get a different font.